# Android Actionbar Menu Item Title shown in Tablet not in Phone

Tags: android

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.kent.service.engg.controllers.CaseDetailsActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/title_bar_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_home_icon"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

    <item android:id="@+id/title_bar_setting"
          android:icon="@drawable/action_settings_icon"
          android:title="Setting"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

This code working fine in Tablet but it is not working in Phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item android:id="@+id/title_bar_setting"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_settings_icon"
      android:title="Setting"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```

Here attribute value : "ifRoom" will neglate text if there is no space in actionbar of phone

Comment: thanks for answer. I use showAsAction="always|withText" also. but same result